# How do I properly move an image using UIAccelerometer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i have implementing moving image using UIAccelerometer.I have used below code.

code:

```
float gravX = (acceleration. x * kFilteringFactor) + (gravX * (1 - kFilteringFactor));
float gravY = (acceleration. y * kFilteringFactor) + (gravY * (1 - kFilteringFactor));
float moveX = acceleration. x - gravX;
float moveY = acceleration. y - gravY;  
CGPoint MoveCenter = [moveImage center];
float Movex = moveX * 30 + MoveCenter. x;
float Movey = moveY * 30 + MoveCenter. y;
moveImage.center = CGPointMake(Movex, Movey);
```

In this code there is one problem.If i move device on top side then image is moving on left side,if device is move left side then image is moving top side.can you give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a problem of the coordinates. **I'm not sure this is the problem** but in Quartz the (0,0) is on bottom left while on UIKit is on top left.

Try to change the coordinates with *frame.origin.x* and *frame.origin.y* instead of using CGPoint.